# How to read data from specific buffer with glreadpixels based on GLES30 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

As I understood, from GLES30 there is no more `gl_FragColor` buffer (I saw it [HERE](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles3-quick-reference-card.pdf))

Since I can't read a "Special Variables ", how can I read an "out" buffer?

This is my code:

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "#version 300 es\n"+
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
        "in vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "out vec4 fragColor ;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    vec4 tc = texture(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "    fragColor.r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    fragColor.g = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    fragColor.b = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

Here I tried to read the data:

```
 ByteBuffer mPixelBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mWidth * mHeight * 4);
            mPixelBuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

GLES30.glReadPixels(startX, startY, frameWidth, frameHeight, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mPixelBuf);
```

There are no gl errors in the code.

The output `mPixelBuf` only zeroes.

How can I make sure that `fragColor` is reading?

Thanks

**Update1- Full Texture Render Code:**

```
package com.MES.YOtm.AnalyzingAdapter;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES30;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Code for rendering a texture onto a surface using OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */
public class STextureRender {

    private static final String TAG = "Myopengl";
    private int zoom;
    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
    private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
    };

    private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;


    private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
            "#version 300 es\n"+
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
            "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
            "in  vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "in  vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
            "out vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
            "    vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
            "}\n";
//Smapler2D
    private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
            "#version 300 es\n"+
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 : require\n" +
            "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
            "in vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "uniform mediump sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
            "layout(location = 0)  out mediump vec4 fragColor ;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    vec4 tc = texture(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
            "    fragColor.r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
            "    fragColor.g = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
            "    fragColor.b = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
            "}\n";



    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

    private int mProgram;
    private int mTextureID = -12345;
    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int muSTMatrixHandle;
    private int maPositionHandle;
    private int maTextureHandle;

    public STextureRender(int _zoom) {
        Log.v("My Error", "Start STextureRender constructor");
        try
        {

            mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                    mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
            zoom = _zoom;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.v("My Error", "STextureRender Error = " + ex.toString());
       }
        Log.v("My Error", "End STextureRender constructor");
    }

    public int getTextureId() {
        return mTextureID;
    }

    /**
     * Draws the external texture in SurfaceTexture onto the current EGL surface.
     */
    public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st, boolean invert) {
        checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
        try
        {
            st.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
            if (invert) {
                mSTMatrix[5] = -mSTMatrix[5];
                mSTMatrix[13] = 1.0f - mSTMatrix[13];
            }

            GLES30.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES30.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            checkGlError("glUseProgram");

            GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
            GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
            GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

            GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.v("My Error", "drawFrame Error = " + ex.toString());
       }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes GL state.  Call this after the EGL surface has been created and made current.
     */
    public void surfaceCreated() {
        try
        {
            mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("failed creating program");
            }
            maPositionHandle = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
            if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
            }
            maTextureHandle = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
            if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
            }

            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
            if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
            }

            muSTMatrixHandle = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
            if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
            }

            int[] textures = new int[1];
            GLES30.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

            mTextureID = textures[0];
            GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
            checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

            GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                    GLES30.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                    GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                    GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                    GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            checkGlError("glTexParameter");
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.v("My Error", "surfaceCreated Error = " + ex.toString());
       }
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the fragment shader.  Pass in null to reset to default.
     */
    public void changementShader(String fragmentShader) {
        try
        {
        if (fragmentShader == null) {
            fragmentShader = FRAGMENT_SHADER;
        }
        GLES30.glDeleteProgram(mProgram);
        mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, fragmentShader);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            Log.v("My Error", "failed creating program");
            throw new RuntimeException("failed creating program");
        }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.v("My Error", " changementShader Error = " + ex.toString());
       }
    }

    private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
        try
        {
            int shader = GLES30.glCreateShader(shaderType);
            checkGlError("glCreateShader type=" + shaderType);

            GLES30.glShaderSource(shader, source);
            GLES30.glCompileShader(shader);
            int[] compiled = new int[1];
            GLES30.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES30.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                Log.e(TAG, " " + GLES30.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                GLES30.glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }

            return shader;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.v("My Error", "loadShader Error = " + ex.toString());
           return 0;
       }
    }

    private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
        try
        {
            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
            if (vertexShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
            if (pixelShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int program = GLES30.glCreateProgram();
            checkGlError("glCreateProgram");
            if (program == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create program");
            }
            GLES30.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES30.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES30.glLinkProgram(program);
            int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES30.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES30.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
            if (linkStatus[0] != GLES30.GL_TRUE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                Log.e(TAG, GLES30.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                GLES30.glDeleteProgram(program);
                program = 0;
            }
            return program;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.v("My Error", "createProgram Error = " + ex.toString());
           return 0;
       }
    }

    public void checkGlError(String op) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES30.glGetError()) != GLES30.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shader code is totally irrelevant to what `glReadPixels` reads, and it has nothing to do with special variable names. It reads from the currently bound read framebuffer; i.e. `glReadPixels` in ES 3.0 works in exactly the same way as it used to work in ES 2.0.

The only exception is multiple render target support, but that's not relevant in this case.

> How can I make sure that fragColor is reading?

```
glClearColor(some interesting color)
glClear(COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glReadPixels()
assert color == some interesting color
```

Comment: In GLES 20 I've load the data from mp4 file to "gl_FragColor" special variable and the data read by using GLES20.glReadPixels(startX, startY, frameWidth, frameHeight, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                           mPixelBuf);
Since there is no more "gl_FragColor", how should I read the data from the "out" variable that I've created?

Comment: As is said, it doesn't matter what the variable is called. glReadPixels reads from the current read framebuffer. Your shader can have *any* variable name, and it will work exactly the same way,

Comment: So, Why am I get only zeroes? Is "Texture" function is implemented right in order to read 4 type of  colors(RGBA)?

Comment: I will update the full code for how I user the Buffer.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually seem to include either of the bits of code mentioned in your original question ...

Comment: It is the same, I'm just continue trying to figure what is my problem so the only changes I've made are the location and the mediump that was added to fragcolor

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned is that your `GLES30.glReadPixels` call needs to be done before eglSwapBuffers because `glReadBuffer` is initially set to `GL_BACK` in double-buffered configurations according to document of `glReadBuffer`. Once `eglSwapBuffers` calls `glReadPixels` reads nothing back to main memory.

Comment: I don't use eglSwapBuffers , Is it necessary to use it? If yes, how should I implement it in GLES30?